# Debian network monitoring like tkinet

Tags: debian, monitoring, networking

in earlier Debian versions there was a network monitoring tool called tkinet. It did create a network map and it pinged continuously configured resources. When something did not work, the resource in the map has changed colour/issued a warning.

What tool can be used in debian to create a map like that? I was looking for something like tkinet, but I was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with nagios core (http://www.nagios.org/download/core)? Otherwise there is watchdog (http://www.sat.dundee.ac.uk/~psc/watchdog/Linux-Watchdog.html) that is much lighter.

Comment: I'll take a look at watchdog and maybe on nagios if watchdog was not good enough. Thank you very much